# Appropriate terminology for classifying some assumptions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation, random-variables, terminology

I would like your help in order to choose the appropriate terminology for classifying the assumptions below.

Consider a random vector $X\equiv (X_1,X_2,X_3)$.

Let $\Delta X\equiv (X_1-X_3, X_2-X_3, X_1-X_2)$ with probability distribution denoted by $P_{\Delta X}$ whose marginals are $(P_{\Delta X})_k$  for $k\in \{1,2,3\}$.

Take the following possible assumptions on $P_{\Delta X}$:

**(1)** $(P_{\Delta X})_1=(P_{\Delta X})_2=(P_{\Delta X})_3$

**(2)** $(P_{\Delta X})_k$ has median zero   $\forall k\in \{1,2,3\}$

**(3)** $(P_{\Delta X})_k$  is symmetric around zero  $\forall k\in \{1,2,3\}$

Assumptions (1), (2), (3) are all implications of assuming

**(4)** $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ are exchangeable.

---

**Question:** I would like your help to find a generic and common way to refer to assumptions (1), (2), (3).

At the moment I thought about

"*(1), (2), (3) are assumptions imposing various degrees of symmetry on $P_{\Delta X}$*"

motivated by the fact that (1), (2), (3) are implications of exchangeability which is indeed an assumption of symmetry. However, I don't like this taxonomy very much because of the word "symmetry" which may confuse the reader since it appears also in (3).

Also, I don't want to explicitly mention the fact that (1), (2), (3) are implications of exchangeability, such as something like

"*(1), (2), (3) are different implications of exchangeability*"

Any better suggestion?

Comment: Assumption (2) is redundant, given (3), isn't it?

Comment: Yes yes. I'm not imposing them all together necessarily. In one situation one can impose just (2). In another one can impose (1) and (3), etc.